# Unity 3D CustomDebugger with timeScale = 0 not stopping FixedUpdate

Tags: unity-game-engine

Making a debugger that starts when you press a button while the scene is playing. Once debugging is true, the game needs to completely pause at the point a function called DebugStep is called in the code, then resume from that point forward. Here is my script attached to a canvas button

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ToggleDebugButton : MonoBehaviour {

//private TimeDebugger timeDebugger;

[Header("Debugger")]
public bool isDebugging;
public string debugStep;

[Header("Basic Properties")]
public bool isMoving;
public bool isAttacking;
public bool isSwinging;
private BasicProperties basicProperties;

void Start()
{
    basicProperties = GameObject.Find("MrPresident").GetComponent<BasicProperties>();
    isDebugging = false;
    GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(TogglePause);
}
public void TogglePause()
{
    isDebugging = !isDebugging;
    if ( !isDebugging )
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }  
}

public void FixedUpdate()
{
    DebugStep("DebugUpdateEnd");
}

public void DebugStep(string source)
{
    if (isDebugging)
    {
        isMoving = basicProperties.isMoving;
        isAttacking = basicProperties.isAttacking;
        isSwinging = basicProperties.isSwinging;

        debugStep = source;
        print("start set timescale 0");
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        print("end set timescale 0");
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that when DebugStep is called in FixedUpdate, the first print statement and second print statement execute, even after timescale has been set to 0 in between them. This is a bigger problem when I try to call DebugStep from inside FixedUpdate in other scripts, where I want the whole FixedUpdate script after the DebugStep call to pause, then proceed from that point when I unpause.

I don't think this is happening, because when I've placed 2 DebugStep calls in a FixedUpdate elsewhere, both are always called, back to back, when the timeScale should have been set to 0 and stopped code execution after the first call. I'm thinking that all of the FixedUpdates that are part of the current FixedUpdate cycle in all scripts finish even if timeScale is set to 0 in the middle of it. Am I correct? Actually I'm really not sure because if I have 2+ calls to DebugStep in a FixedUpdate, the game is only stopping once each cycle

Is there a way to change this so that the game completely stops on Timescale = 0, then resumes from that exact point when I set Timescale back to 1? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly, how it should.

From the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html): "timeScale affects all the time and delta time measuring variables of the Time class."

Furthermore it affects how many times the Update, Lateupdate and fixedupdate methods are called.

It does NOT affects the "speed" of code execution.

So when you enter your update method and change the timescale, you will only notice the result after it has exited the update loop. It will not magically stop within the update function, like you are expecting/ hoping.

If you are looking to wait for a specific function to complete before continuing some code block, you might want to use [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).